# Only Crash logs showing in Device Console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslog

Using Xcode 12, and NSLog to log my messages. When I open the "Window -> Devices and Simulators" and I view the log files of my App on my iPhone, I only see Crash logs (crash logs of my and others' apps). Is there a way to see just my regular logging messages? NSLog output is showing in the console, no problem.  Thanks....

Comment: NSLog will write to console if it can find one (when in debug mode) when in release mode it cant find a console so it wont, if your intention is to write some logs for debug purposes you cant achieve that with simple `NSLog` you can use third party services. If you are tracking something you can use Newrelic, firebase, and many other tools available, if you wanna write a custom text so you can analyze crashes you can try fabric, not sure of complexity of problem you are addressing here

Comment: I had a crash that was happening when the App was not launched by Xcode, but when launched in Xcode, all was well (and I was able to see NSLog output in Xcode's console).  So, I thought it would have been useful to see the NSLog in Device's logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Swift 5.3, Xcode 12, iOS 14 — *No need for a third party service or library*)</sub>

In short: You can replace your `NSLog` calls with calls to `Logger`.

---

You need to create a `Logger` object (somewhere, your preference). If you want, you can make your logging easier to filter, e.g. in the Console app, by making various loggers for different parts/functions in your app.

```
import os.log

let downloadLogger = Logger(subsystem: "My app", category: "Downloading")
let somethingLogger = Logger(subsystem: "My app", category: "Lorem ipsum")
```

Then you call your logger like this:

```
// Some error occurs, so we log it:
downloadLogger.error("Error downloading feed contents: \(error, privacy: .public)")

// Some less important log:
somethingLogger.info("Secret has been stored: \(mySecret, privacy: .private(mask: .hash))")
```

N.B. our secret is kept secret by applying `.private(mask: .hash)`.

To view and filter your logs, on the *Devices* screen, below the *View Device Logs* you'll find *Open Console*.

As the article source states:

> "If you’d like to gather logs from a device, even when your app is not
> running anymore, you can use the `log` command on your Mac with the
> `collect` option
> …
> The `logarchive` file that you get can then be opened in the Console app and filtered just like live logs can."

`sudo log collect --device --start "2020-06-25 16:10:00" --output myapp.logarchive`

---

(Credits: [source](https://wwdcbysundell.com/2020/meet-the-new-logger-api/))